# ListPopupWindow closes soft keyboard

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-popupwindow

Working on a lockscreen app I see a very strange behaviour: showing a ListPopupWindow forces the soft keyboard to close. This happens only on a "lockscreen" activity (activity window flags are set to FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD) and only if keyguard pin/password is set.

Here is a code example:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());
        popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        popupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
            getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")));
        popupWindow.setAnchorView(editText);
        popupWindow.show();
});
```

When popup list appears the keyboards immediately disappears.

Note that at the same time PopupWindow works ok:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) ->  {
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getContext());
        popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        popupWindow.setContentView(new TextClock(getContext()));
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(editText);
});
```

Both the popup window and the keyboard are visible.

Any idea of how to avoid this keyboard disappearance? Finally I need a SearchView (it displays suggestions in a ListPopupWindow) to work properly on a lockscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the keyboard is not closed if the popup window input method mode is 
INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE.

SearchView contains AutoCompleteTextView that changes its suggestions popup input method mode to INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED or INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED. So the workaround is to keep PopupWindow.mInputMethodMode = INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE.

I solved this by creating a custom PopupWindow with setInputMethodMode() overridden:

```
public class SearchSuggestionPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {

    SearchSuggestionPopupWindow(final Context context, final PopupWindow original) {
        super(context);

        setElevation(original.getElevation());

        setAnimationStyle(original.getAnimationStyle());

        setBackgroundDrawable(original.getBackground());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            setOverlapAnchor(original.getOverlapAnchor());
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setEnterTransition(original.getEnterTransition());
            setExitTransition(original.getExitTransition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setInputMethodMode(final int mode) {
        super.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE);
    }
}
```

Then it's necessary to get AutoCompleteTextView from SearchView:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView textView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

and to substitute the custom popup window:

```
final Field listPopupField = AutoCompleteTextView.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
final ListPopupWindow listPopup = (ListPopupWindow) listPopupField.get(textView);

final Field popupField = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
popupField.setAccessible(true);
final PopupWindow popup = (PopupWindow) popupField.get(listPopup);
final PopupWindow customPopup = new SearchSuggestionPopupWindow(textView.getContext(), popup);
popupField.set(listPopup, customPopup);
```